# Call Function Cross Thread in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

i have a Grid in WindowsForms called `grid1`.

i know want to call `grid1.Series.Clear()` from another thread.

Right now i am getting the usual cross thread exception that a thread is touching grid1 but another thread created it.

I find plenty of examples how to call direct functions of grid1.

But how to do it with Calling `Clear()` Function from SeriesCollection "Series" within grid1?

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following:

```
grid1.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => grid1.Series.Clear()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help.

If you wanna create a function for that, this is an example.

```
delegate void FunctionNameCallBack(InputParams);
private void FunctionName(InputParams)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        var d = new FunctionNameCallBack(FunctionName);
        this.Invoke(d, InputParams);
    }
    else
    {
        // Your Code here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is run on a thread other than the thread which created the grid1 control

```
grid1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => grid1.Series.Clear()));
```

Comment: What is wrong with this answer?